# What does desktop_Exec mean?

Tags: application-development

In a review for my click package, the message contained this bit:

```
desktop_Exec
```

What do I bear in mind to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error messages like this can sometimes look like the following:

```
"absolute path '/usr/bin/qmlscene -I ./modules/ ./app/saucybacon.qml' for Exec given in .desktop file.",
```

It's important that you don't use absolute paths because

1. they can change
2. you might be relying on somethign that is available locally on your development machine and not on the actual device.